# CTRL + W hotkey does not function

Tags: scripting, workflow, maya, hotkeys

I like to speed up my workflow in Maya, therefore I like to create custom scripts and bind hotkeys to them.

But when I bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to a custom script it does not work when I press the corresponding key.

my script just says:

```
print 'hello'
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is a system hotkey for closing windows, id suggest switching over to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> instead.

Comment: Sadly alt + W is alread used by another hotkey within Maya, but your answer is probably right

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use Auto Hotkey to register all reserved hotkey combinations as key combinations that Maya finds acceptabe. For example rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and assign something useful to that.